# How to make Linux shared object(.so) from (.lib)?

Tags: python, c, linux, shared-libraries

I have some motion controller i want to talk with in linux.

Right now i have .dll(working great in windows) .lib file and .h file for C code.

Please help me to make .SO (linux .dll) file from .dll .lib .h

Thanks you!!!

Comment: That doesn't work like you apparently think. Do you have the source code for the *dll*. The *.c* files, not the headers?

Comment: What does Python have to do with your question?

Comment: i don't have the source code.

Comment: Friends, i have to say i am not expert in linking compiling etc... appreciate step by step explanation

Comment: @PavelGolubev If you don't have the source code then I have bad news for you. You can't do what you want to do basically. You need to recompile the source code for Linux to make a shared object which you can't because you don't have access to it.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks friends. I will contact the controller company and ask them to compile for linux.